# Trigger with a validation rule not working as expected

Tags: visualforce, trigger, validation-rule

I'm facing a weird issue with trigger and validation rule. 
The requirement here is 
When User enters comment information it should be appended with the user lastname along with the timestamp ---Done by trigger

```
trigger CommentsUpdate on Account (before Update,before insert) 
{
if(trigger.isbefore){
    for(Account a: Trigger.new){
                  system.debug('trigger old map--'+trigger.oldMap);
                    if(oldAcc.Comments__c !=null && a.Comments__c.trim() != oldAcc.Comments__c.trim()){
                       system.debug('comments change block');
                       a.Comments__c += '   '+userinfo.getlastname()+' '+system.now();           
                   }else if(oldAcc.Comments__c ==null){
           a.Comments__c += '   '+userinfo.getlastname()+' '+system.now();       
        }
        }}}
```

And when a user tries to delete or modify the previous comments then a validation message should be displayed.Instead he can add the new comments along with the previous one --- Done with validation rule

```
AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Comments__c)), NOT(CONTAINS(Comments__c,(PRIORVALUE(Comments__c))))
```

My problem here is when I try to edit a previous commented one validation rule is triggering.here is the screenshot
[image]

In this case I should be able to add new comments but why it is throwing me the error

Comment: can u show me full trigger code

Comment: I don't understand. In your validation rule, you check if the current comment doesn't contain the previous value of your comment. This is why it's not working.

Comment: added the full code.Martin it contains the previous comment, i have added test5 now and tried to save.it is throwing the error

Comment: Where you initializing `oldAcc` in the trigger? Can you deactivate the trigger and check if the validation rule is still failing or not?

Comment: I'm not initializing it anywhere.Should I initialize? And the trigger is working fine in the morning IST and getting error in the evening times.very weird